# Send form data and generated pdf from orbeon to web service

Tags: orbeon

Is it possible to setup Orbeon Forms to send data entered in form **and** pdf to another site or web service? I tried using workflow-send button as described in http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Workflow-send-button, but it in this case only xml data or pdf is send to success page.

Is there any other way to get data entered by user and generated PDF to another web application? I am new to this area, so it's possible that I missed something obvious in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: when using the [workflow send](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Workflow-send-button) button and a POST or PUT, either a URL pointing to the PDF or the XML document is sent to the success or error page. However, the *document id* is also sent as the `document` request parameter. So I would:

1. Set the properties to have the PDF generated, so the PDF is sent in the POST or PUT.
2. In the target page, retrieve the PDF from the URL, and the XML from the persistence layer, using the document id provided to you in the `document` request parameter.

Sending the `document` as a request parameter was implemented after the 3.9 release, so you'll need to use Orbeon Forms 4.0 or newer (as of this writing you can use [4.0 M6](http://blog.orbeon.com/2012/07/orbeon-forms-40-m6.html)).